# Pentaho report designer , checkbox parameter checked by default

Tags: pentaho

we have set a check box parameter in Pentaho report designer .
When we launch the report the check box is unchecked .
what we want is , to set the default value of that Check box to be checked 
so when we launch the report we don't have to check it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question: And how would you do the same things on Pentaho cde?

Answer:

Step1: First create one simple datasource.

=> Datasource name: query
=> Query:
SELECT "option1"
UNION
SELECT "option2"
UNION
SELECT "option3"
UNION
SELECT "option4"
UNION
SELECT "option5"

Step2:- Goto component panel and then select "Check Component". click on advanced properties.
Name: checkcomponent,
Parameter: checked, 
Datasource: query, 
HtmlObject: panel_1 (assumption), 
preexecution: function f(){checked = ['option1','option2'];}

that's it run dashboard and see. Defaultly option1 and option2 are selected.

Thank you.

Comment: I haven't understand yet the options in your query

Comment: i.e static sql's simple, take that sql and paste in mysql and execute and see you can understand easily.